# Add separator looping through jade

Tags: node.js, express, pug

```
-if(result)
   each this, i in result.persons
    p= name.name || "NA"
```

above jade print

```
James
John
```

how to add separator for example a , in between?

Answer (score 0):

You can check `i`, which holds the current array index, and use that to check if the current name should be prefixed with a comma (which is always, *except* for the first entry, where `i` equals 0):

```
each name, i in result.persons
  p= (i === 0 ? '' : ', ') + (name.name || "NA")
```

(and perhaps change `<p>` to an inline element like `<span>`, but that's entirely dependent on your particular setup)

Comment: this will also add `,` after the last item like `john, james,`

Comment: @Jennifer it shouldn't, unless there's maybe a last entry in `result.persons` that has a `name` property that consists of whitespace (or some other "invisible" character(s)).

Comment: Your loop says if it's the first iteration don't do anything else add a comma, doesn't that means I will have a comma too at the very last iteration?

Comment: @Jennifer the code says _"if it's the first iteration, don't do anything, else add a comma **before** the name"_. So the comma is used as a prefix for the name, also for the last one, but that's intended.